# Possible to change the group name for imported sub-flows?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am importing [sub-flows](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/#Re-usable_Flow_Snippets) as so:

```
import :mbist_prehvs_flow
import :mbist_hvs_flow
import :mbist_posthvs_flow
```

Is it possible to change the flow group name by passing an option to the import method?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like passing in a `:name` option might work, have you tried that?

https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/origen_ext/generator/flow.rb#L34

```
import :mbist_prehvs_flow, name: 'my_flow_name'
```

Comment: Can this name be queried then during the shutdown callback?

Comment: I would expect such a name option to be present in the options passed into the shutdown callback handler